# Accessing items within linked "Resource File"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Forms application in C# that uses a lot images across multiple projects under the solution; I've created a new project that compiles to a DLL to [house all of the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmeMJ.jpg) to clean things up a bit & [linked the resulting "*.res" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM8ZI.jpg) into each of the projects.

How can I now access the images stored in this new project? I can't seem to get access to the `ResourceTemplate` `assembly/namespace` & have had no luck finding information specific to linking resources using the `Resource File` option in the project `Properties> Application` window.

I'm currently testing with "**System.Resources.ResourceManager**" & using the `GetObject()` method and will see if I can load images directly from the DLL using `System.Uri` next.

Comment: It appears this question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550354/net-resource-dll-with-multiple-resx-files), which has no resolution. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why you didn't use .resx files as embedded resource in your resource assembly and then in other projects add its reference?

Comment: I initially wanted to use it purely for icons, mimicking the icon store functionality of "shell32.dll" but then wanted to see if I could use it for images in general, I'm now interested to see if it's a possibility.

Comment: I really don't know whats the difference between .net assembly resources and win32 dll resources. but take a look at my answer [here]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/32492906/3110834), there i extract embedded resource from assembly, that is about .net resources. Hope you find it helpful:)

Comment: But after you satisfied your interest in those kind of resource, I strongly recommend using .resx files in a dll that will be add as a reference in other projects. this way wil be extremely easy and friendly

Comment: Excellent, thank you I'll have a play around with that sample. From the trouble I've had with this I agree, I'm definitely sticking with the "*.resx" route in future.

Comment: Let me know if the solution helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResouceReader` from `System.Resouces`.

first of all load the `assembly` containing the resources and get the resource stream out of it:

```
Assembly resourcesAssembly = Assembly.Load("C:\fullPath.asm");
string[] Names = resourcesAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
Stream resourceStream = a.GetManifestResourceStream(names[0]);
```

now using `ResourceReader` we will get the serialized resources stored in the resources `assembly`:

```
ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(resourceStream);
```

And take the resource we want using it's name:

```
byte[] serializedResource;
string resourceType;
reader.GetResourceData("ResourceNameWithoutExtension", out resourceType, out serializedResource);
```

Now all we need is to deserialize the resource using `BinaryFormatter` from `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary`:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream serializedResourceStream = new MemoryStream(serializedResource))
{
    object result = b.Deserialize(serializedResourceStream);
}
```

Hope this helps, it works for me, feel free to ask questions :)